# Not in scope: `HashMap.lookup'

Tags: json, haskell, hashmap

I am having trouble with HashMap.lookup function. Please give your advise on how to fix following code (I am getting Not in scope: `HashMap.lookup' error):

```
instance JSON.FromJSON Document where
  parseJSON (JSON.Object v) = maybe mzero parser $ HashMap.lookup "document" v
    where parser (JSON.Object v') = Document <$> v' JSON..: "name"
                                        <*> v' JSON..: "content"
          parser _           = mzero
  parseJSON _          = mzero
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add

```
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as HashMap
```

on top of your source file.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you are importing the package. If you are using something like:

```
import Data.HashMap
```

Then you can access the `Data.HashMap.lookup` function as simply:

```
lookup
```

however you may have a conflict with `Prelude.lookup`, in this case you can either add an explicit `Prelude` import hiding the `lookup` function, i.e. add:

```
import Prelude hiding (lookup)
```

at the top of the file, or use the full name:

```
Data.HashMap.lookup
```

Note that you cannot simply use `HashMap.lookup`. The module is called `Data.HashMap` not just `HashMap`.

---

You may want to give an alias to the package, such as:

```
import Data.HashMap as H
```

And then use:

```
H.lookup key hashmap
```

This will still allow to use non-prefixed version of types/functions if they don't overlap with something else. If you want to be safe you can use a qualified import:

```
import qualified Data.HashMap as H
```

In this way *everything* from the `HashMap` module *must* be prefixed with `H.`. Even the types:

```
-- note: H.HashMap *not* HashMap:
somefunction :: H.HashMap String [Int] -> [Int]
```

Without `qualified` you *could* still write:

```
somefunction :: HashMap String [Int] -> [Int]
```

And you'd have to use `H.` only when calling some functions.

---

Note that there are different packages proving `HashMap`. You may want to use `Data.HashMap.Lazy` or `Data.HashMap.Strict`.